# Show a sequence of lines bunches up or isn't in an element of a topology

Tags: general-topology, limits, convergence-divergence

Statement:

> Let $L_1, L_2, L_3, \ldots$ be a sequence of parallel lines in the plane, and put $X = \cup_{n\ge 1} L_n$. Define topology $\tau$ on $X$ by $G$ is $\tau$- open if $G = \varnothing $ or $\exists n_0 \in \mathbb N$ such that $L_n \setminus G$ is finite for every $n \ge n_0$.

> Given an arbitrary sequence $(z_n)$ in $X$, verify either some subsequence of $(z_n)$ lies on one single line $L_q$ or there is a subsequence and a non-empty open set $G$ such that no term in the subsequence belongs to $G$.

Solution:

Looks like $\tau$ is cofinite meaning if $(L_n)$ is convergent, it's eventually constant. Suppose $(L_n)$ converges. Then there’s some natural $n_0$ s.t. $L_n = L_q$ for all $n \ge n_0$. That means every $L_{n_i} \in \{L_{n_0}, L_{n_1}, L_{n_2}, \ldots\}$ lies on $L_q$.

If $(L_n)$ does not converge to $L_q$, then there’s some neighborhood $G$ of $L_q$ s.t. $L_n$ are not in $G$ for any $n$.

Does this solution make sense?

edit:

Since $\tau$ is cofinite, convergent $(z_n)$ implies it's eventually constant. Suppose $(z_n)$ converges. Then there’s some natural $n_0$ s.t. $z_n = L_q$ for all $n \ge n_0$. That means every $z_{n_i} \in \{z_{n_0}, z_{n_1}, z_{n_2}, \ldots\}$ lies on $L_q$.

If $(z_n)$ does not converge to $L_q$, then there’s some neighborhood $G$ of $L_q$ s.t. $z_n$ are not in $G$ for any $n$.

Comment: All those $(L_n)$ should be $(z_n)$ right?

Comment: @ArcticChar, right. The first quoted part in the OP used to be a part of its own problem. This one simply refers to it. Guess the authors didn't feel like repeating the statement of that problem with the new notation again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation $(z_n)$ is quite confusing: the $n$ in $z_n$ has nothing to do with the $n$ in the lines $L_n$. I change it to $(z_k)$.

This almost has nothing to do with topology, just elementary set theory: For each $n$, let $Z_n = \{ k \in \mathbb N: z_k \in L_n\}$.

If $Z_n$ is infinite for some $n$, there is a subsequence $(z_{k_j})$ in the line $L_n$.

If not, then $Z_n$ is finite for all $n\in Z$. Let $C_n = \{ z_k : k \in Z_n\}$. Then $C_n$ is a finite set in $L_n$. Let $G = X\setminus \cup_n C_n$. Then there is no $z_k$ in $G$.

Comment: Thanks. Does the solution in my OP still make sense? I am guessing this is just a routine exercise for showing sequence convergence in top. spaces. Also, it's kind of a warm-up/foreshadowing for a problem(that has to do with the Arens–Fort space) that immediately succeeds it.

Comment: @user947160 may be you should fix the $(L_n)$, $(z_n)$ issue that I mentioned first? Now your solution does not even make sense.....

Comment: @ Arctic Char, take a look at the statements as written in the book: (1) https://ibb.co/xJRq0sd (2) https://ibb.co/qNQ8d3F I am thinking they just meant $(z_n) = (L_n)$. Not sure how that changes anything. Can you elaborate?

Comment: In the picture there is no mention of $(z_n)$ at all. That is just the definition of $G$. @user947160. No, $(z_n)$ is not $(L_n)$. $(z_n)$ is a sequence in $X$, so each $z_k$ is an element in $X$, not a subset  $L_n$.

Comment: @ Arctic Char, I made an edit to my OP. Please, see if that makes sense now.

Comment: First of all, $\tau$ is not the cofinite topology. Indeed, it restrict to the discrete topology on each lines $L_n$. So it is true that if $(z_n)$ stays in one line and is convergent, then it is eventually constant. But apriori, we do not know if a convergent sequence would stay in one particular line (with some works, one can actually show that, but you did not show that) @user947160

Comment: and when $(z_n)$ does not converge, there is basically nothing you can say. I don't think splitting the two cases (convergent and non-convergent) would help you. As I said, the result has nothing to do with topology.

Comment: @ Arctic Char, thanks. I'll just skip this problem.